# How to access an nxm array in matlab from the bottom left?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

what I am trying to do is to write a function that computes the sum of the elements of A that are in the lower right triangular part of A, that is,
elements in the counter-diagonal (going from the bottom left corner, up and to the right) and
elements that are to the right of it. If given matrix A below the function would return the sum of: 7+5+3+8+6+9. The matrix is not neccesary a nxn matrix.

I am trying to do that but since i just started with matlab i am not sure how to access the indexes with the for loop (starting from the left).

some hints/help would be appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this method (works well for nxn matrix): Flip horizontally the matrix and calculate the sum of the elements of the lower triangular matrix

```
s=sum(sum(tril(A(:,end:-1:1))))
```